# How to implement Group Chat using Appsync Graphql?

Tags: reactjs, aws-amplify, graphql-subscriptions

Present I have list users and also each user conversation list but trying to implement Group Chat to add multiple users to chat once at a time using Amplify, GraphQL and React JS.

Comment: please describe what you've done so far, and please show some code

Comment: This is the reference i have taken.

https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-mobile-appsync-chat-starter-angular

I have created registered users and there conversation list using GraphQL subscriptions, queries and mutations. Now I am planning to create Group chat using registered users but need schema of GraphQL on how to create group chat.